# Using CASE-IF-ELSE Conditional statement in Redshift

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, amazon-redshift

How to query with CASE-IF-ELSE Conditions..

[image]

Comment: do you just have company_sequence of 0 and 1 or are those examples?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh I have tried 

select
Name
company sequence
case
  when company sequence = 0 and Title like ('Unemployed')
  then company sequence = 0
  else company sequence = 0
end as sequence,
title,
start,
end
from Contact_Table

Comment: @JonScott sequence is based on the latest job until the previous job.
0 = 3rd job
1 = 2nd job
2 = 1st job..

if the person applied for a new job. new job will be sequence = 0.
then old job pushes to seq 1.

Comment: what if both condition1 and condition2 are met - what if neither are met? please update your question with teh sql you have tried so far